# Convert comma separated strings into list quickly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a mySQL table that looks something like this:

```
>> customer_table

customerId  | list1   |  list2    | list3
--------------------------------------------
     0      | 0,1,2,3 | 3,2,443,3| 3,55,3,4
--------------------------------------------
     1      | 5,1,8,9 | 5,2,41,6 | 1,5,3,90
```

The column customerId is an int primary key. The rest of the fields are lists of comma separated strings (so list1 is '0,1,2,3' etc) stored in mediumtext fields. Each mediumtext field is roughly 500,000 characters long (nearly 120,000 numbers in there) so very large.

I want to query this table so that I can quickly convert a list into numbers and then take the ith elements of that parsed list and return them. I will mostly be querying one row of customer_table at a time, although maybe sometimes more if the process is quick. The pseudo-code (poorly written) would look something like this

```
>> select csv_parsed(list1) # need to search a parsed version of the list
from customer_table 
where customerId = 0 
and index = 0 or index = 1 or index = 4 # These are the ith elements of the parsed list
```

should return something along the lines of:

```
>> customerId | 0  | 1 | 4 
   -----------------------
       0      | 0  | 1 | 3
```

Comment: In a technical sense, this isn't really a mysql table - but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, I'm not sure what the relationship is between the article you've posted and my question? The sample table I've drawn in the question is exactly what our database looks like as implemented in mysql

Comment: Well, when you figure out the connection, let us know.!

Comment: :) Thanks Strawberry, was being slightly dense there. Will try to improve the question slightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not support queries that have a dynamic select-list. The columns in your select-list are fixed at the time you prepare the query, and the data discovered during execution cannot expand or rename columns in the select-list.

You might like to take a look at [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). This is a builtin function in MySQL that can pick out substrings delimited by a character you want.

```
select customerId, 
  substring_index(substring_index(list1, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS 0,
  substring_index(substring_index(list1, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS 1,
  substring_index(substring_index(list1, ',', 4), ',', -1) AS 4,
from customer_table 
where customerId = 0
```

Next time, don't store data in comma-separated strings if you want to work with individual elements in the list.